# Background color for drop down menu options is not working in Safari, Chrome + MAC

Tags: macos, drop-down-menu, safari, cross-browser, osx-leopard

I have a drop down box where I am setting background color of options as gray based on some conditions. The problem is its all work fine with almost browser on windows machine but its not working in Safari & Chrome on MAC OS.

I used color as:

- Color name: `Gray`,
- hex color code: `#CCCCCC` and
- with `rgb(204,204,204)`
  but all of three isn't working.

I done goggling and found that there is some problem with safari in MAC. I am not sure how to fix this. There is an open post at mac forums which didn't replied yet:

http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/web-design-hosting/144101-drop-down-background-color-mac-safari-not-working.html.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @nrsharma Did you find any solution for the above mentioned issue on MAC. I am also facing the same issue while changing colour using 'style' inside <select> tag in jquery.

Comment: No, as mentioned in the answer "the menu that appears when a <select> dropdown menu is activated cannot be styled under some browsers and OSes. You will need to live with the OS default appearance for this control."

Comment: I thought it's been 7 years since you asked this question so there might be some solution to this problem now. But thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, the menu that appears when a `<select>` dropdown menu is activated cannot be styled under some browsers and OSes. You will need to live with the OS default appearance for this control.