# Is it possible to color each row in an html selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an html selector through which the user can pick a color.

```
<select name="color" class="form-control">
  <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
  <option value="ff7f00">Orange</option>
  <option value="ffff00">Yellow</option>
  <option value="7fff00">Chartreuse</option>
  <option value="00ff00">Green</option>
  <option value="00ff7f">Spring Green</option>
  <option value="00ffff">Cyan</option>
  <option value="007fff">Azure</option>
  <option value="0000ff">Blue</option>
  <option value="7f00ff">Violet</option>
  <option value="ff00ff">Magenta</option>
  <option value="ff007f">Rose</option>
</select>
```

I would like to color each option in the picker with the color it represents so the user can see which color they are picking. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: Someone pointed out that I wasn't clear about the fact that I want this color to (ideally) be represented on highlight so you would see something that looks like a paint swatch. If that isn't possible then I'd like to at least change the background color of the picker when a color is selected to that of the selected color.

Comment: You can't style options directly.  You've gotta generate a replacement set of markup that replaces the select box.  Here's an example of how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321986/1514572

Comment: If you want to get fancy, use jQuery for an easier time. Using your value convention: `$(".form-control option").each(function() {
   $(this).css("color","#"+$(this).val());
});`

Comment: You should update your question to mention you want the colour to be as represented **on highlight**. Then add `javascript` & `jquery` tags so that someone can help you with a JS solution, as doing this on highlight is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: @setek, thanks. I updated it.

Comment: @RUJordan, can you show me a fiddle with that working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/Wj42a/1/)

This is the code for acheiving the desired result

**The advantage of using the below code is you just need to add the color you want in the `optionColors` array seperated by comma and it will add it as an option**

**I also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576793/848841) that the background color will not be set to the option in MAC OS !!!**

**HTML**

```
<select name="color" class="form-control" id="Select">
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
optionColors=["red","blue","green","yellow","black"];
    $.each(optionColors,function(i,data){
        $("#Select").append("<option style='background-color:"+optionColors[i]+"'>"+optionColors[i]+"</option>");

    });
    $("#Select").prepend('<option selected="selected" style="background-color:white">Select a color</option>');
});
```

Comment: I still don't see a difference in browser. :(
In your fiddle it just looked like a regular selector.

Comment: you clicked on the select a color ?! I have the background different for each option

Comment: Hmm. Am I missing some JSfiddle library or something? This is what I see. http://picsurge.com/g/a1deP7

Comment: http://picsurge.com/g/zPLpEK
check the image
or else just create a html file and copy paste the contents to it 
dont forget to include jquery1.9.1

Comment: I'm using chrome, too. On a mac. I dunno why it's not showing any difference for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42380/discussion-between-vignesh-and-logan-shire)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Jquery, you don't need to write hardcode css for color, it will take whichever value you give.

[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/9hQ8p/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-control option').each(function(){
        $(this).css('color','#'+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, in OSX it is impossible to style this element. : (

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to, on hover, change the background colour of a `select`'s `option` is impossible without replacing the `select` entirely.

This is a bare bones example of stripping out the keys and values from the HTML, and populating something else with a list of options:

http://jsfiddle.net/yftW6/1/

```
var colorList = {};
var colorKeys = [];

$('.form-control option').each(function(index) {
    colorList[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
});

for (var key in colorList) {
    $('.color-replacer').append('<span class="color-' + key + '">' + colorList[key] + '</span>');
}

$('.color-replacer span').click(function() {
    $('.form-control').val($(this).prop('class').replace('color-', ''));
});
```

Once you click on the replaced option, it goes back and updates the original `select`. You can use jQuery to hide the select so nobody will see it (`$('.form-control').hide();` at the top.)

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work. The drop down is still white with a blue highlighted row.

Comment: You mean on highlight you want the colours to be different? If you mean on highlight, then you are out of luck, you can't do this with CSS alone. You will need to replace the select element entirely (using JS) with custom HTML, so that you can style it exactly how you want. The inner workings of form elements come under the shadowDOM, and so styling for it is largely up to the vendor, not the coder.

Comment: Ideally, yes, during the highlight. If that's not possible then I'd like to change the color of the picker itself to reflect the selected color.

Comment: By 'picker' do you mean the cursor? I've updated this answer to reflect a jQuery solution to populate a different list with elements that will then push it back to the select.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1" style="background-color: blue">Test</option>
  <option value="2" style="background-color: green">Test</option>
</select>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S8RC3/12/)

Comment: I didn't see a difference in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="color">
  <option value="ff0000" style="background-color:ff0000" >Red</option>
  <option value="ff7f00" style="background-color:ff7f00">Orange</option>
  <option value="ffff00" style="background-color:ffff00">Yellow</option>
  <option value="7fff00" style="background-color:7fff00">Chartreuse</option>
  <option value="00ff00" style="background-color:00ff00">Green</option>
  <option value="00ff7f" style="background-color:00ff7f">Spring Green</option>
  <option value="00ffff" style="background-color:00ffff">Cyan</option>
  <option value="007fff" style="background-color:007fff">Azure</option>
  <option value="0000ff" style="background-color:0000ff">Blue</option>
  <option value="7f00ff" style="background-color:7f00ff">Violet</option>
  <option value="ff00ff" style="background-color:ff00ff">Magenta</option>
  <option value="ff007f" style="background-color:ff007f">Rose</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector for option.

CSS

```
.optionRed{
  background : red;
}
.optionOrange{
  background :orange;
}
.optionYellow{
  background : yellow;
```

### }

HTML

```
<select name="color">
<option value="ff0000" class="optionRed">Red</option>
<option value="ff7f00" class="optionOrange">Orange</option>
<option value="ffff00" class="optionYellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="7fff00">Chartreuse</option>
<option value="00ff00">Green</option>
<option value="00ff7f">Spring Green</option>
<option value="00ffff">Cyan</option>
<option value="007fff">Azure</option>
<option value="0000ff">Blue</option>
<option value="7f00ff">Violet</option>
<option value="ff00ff">Magenta</option>
<option value="ff007f">Rose</option>
</select>
```

Check the code in

http://jsfiddle.net/VF26G/1/

Comment: I didn't see any difference between rows.